# Can i convert an interger value into a hexadecimal value of type ANSISTRING?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

In Delphi 2010 there's a function `IntToHex()`  which converts an `integer` value into a `hexadecimal` of type `UNICODE string`.

What I need is a function which converts the `integer` into a `hexadecimal` of type `AnsiString`.

Comment: Surely all you need to do is convert a Unicode string to an ansistring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting will work, since hex is always ASCII characters:

```
MyHexString := AnsiString(IntToHex(1234, 4));
```

If you need a function, write a wrapper:

```
function IntToHexAnsi(Value: Integer; Digits: Integer): AnsiString;
begin
  Result := AnsiString(IntToHex(Value, Digits));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special. Just assign a variable of type AnsiString to the result of the IntToHex function - the compiler will take care of converting the UnicodeString/STRING type to AnsiString:

```
VAR
  AnsiStr : AnsiString;

BEGIN
  AnsiStr:=IntToHex(12345678,8);
END;
```

Comment: That could give a warning, though. Better to cast, so the compiler does not complain: `AnsiStr := AnsiString(IntToHex(12345678, 8));`.

Comment: With warnings on, this generates [dcc32 Warning] Project1.dpr(14): W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString', which is why I didn't post this as my answer. The code in my answer does not generate that warning.